# Why my 'at' clause command execute the shell immediately and ignored the time limit?

Tags: command-line, bash, at-command

I wrote a shell named **t.sh**  It's content is:

```
touch 88888
```

The command I'm using is

```
sh t.sh | at 03:13Jun15
```

After I execute this command, I got this show on my screen:

```
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 9 at Sun Jun 15 03:13:00 2014
```

It shows quite clear that this will be executed at Sun Jun 15 03:13:00 2014

But when I check my folder, and I find a 88888 file exists there. Rmoved it and try agian, still the same result.

What's the problems here? Would it be a bash/sh thing? Because I saw it says will execute by /bin/sh?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`at` reads commands from standard input, or from a file if you specify the `-f` flag.
What `sh t.sh | at [time]` does is:

```
1. execute the shell script t.sh *right now*; 
2. pipe the output of the shell script to at.
```

But the script has no output, so there is nothing to execute on Sunday.

What you want is `at 03:13Jun15 -f t.sh`.

Comment: Pipes. They still confuse me sometimes.